# Redirect standard output to a log and standard error to an error log

Tags: shell, unix

I have a command, say `find . -size +10`

I need to redirect the error like "permission denied" to errorlog.txt

```
find . -size +10 2>errorlog.txt
```

And to redirect the normal output to standard log file report.txt

```
find . -size +10 >report.txt
```

How to combine these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
command > stdout.log 2> stderr.log
```

or, to also see the output on screen:

```
(command | tee stdout.log) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee stderr.log
```

Answer (score 2):

```
some_command > report.txt 2> errorlog.txt
```